# Why can't the Pi 3 receive FM radio by itself?

Tags: pi-3, radio

I've read online that the Pi 3's WiFi/Bluetooth chip (BCM43438) can also receive FM radio. Why can't I use it to receive FM signals?

Comment: Related [answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28173/20379)

Comment: @Mast Not really. I'm mainly referring to the built-in chipset on the Pi 3.

Comment: This site is not just about you, it's also about what others do when they find your question. For those interested in getting radio to work regardless how it's done, that link could help them. It's related, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Mast I'm aware.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to [this](https://raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=138134&p=917345) the required pin(s) on the BCM43438 were not easy to route out, and so are not connected on the chip.