# 450MHz - 2.4GHz Receiver

Tags: pi-3, radio

There is a device in my house that is broadcasting in the 450MHz - 2.4GHz range. I do not know the exact frequency that the device is broadcasting on. I am looking to use my raspberry pi to receive and decode the signal. Is there a module that would work for this radio signal range. I see there was a question asked about receiving the FM frequency range, but I am looking to receive a higher frequency range. [Receive FM Radio on Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28170/receive-fm-radio-on-raspberry-pi)

I could try the RTL-SDR solution if there is no other solution, but the range doesn't quite reach 2.4GHz

Comment: what is the transmitter device? ... is there no label on the device?

Comment: I found the frequency information for two of the devices
Water: https://sandeen.net/wordpress/energy/neptune-rf-water-meter-frequency-hopping-pattern/
Electric:
http://ewwwsv2.elster.com/downloads/Type_AB_data_sheet.pdf

Comment: I can't find as much information the two gas meters:
http://www.aplisac.com/pdf/AMERICAN%20METER-Catalogo_General.pdf
Possible frequency for other gas meter might be same as their frequency for water meter
https://www.reddit.com/r/RTLSDR/comments/b18jht/anyone_get_readings_from_their_sensus_water_meter/eiklsyi/ so maybe I can use the RTL_SDR dongle

Comment: i think that those devices use encrypted communication ... where are you seeing the 2.4 GHz rating?

Comment: That is frequency range that I found when googling for the frequency range of AMR devices https://lakecountry.civicweb.net/document/36903 The devices might be encrypted, but it seems like other people have been able to decode the data; so I am assuming that it is not encrypted for all devices